# How to get the Item id from a one drive url

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am programmatically trying to access a one-drive file (excel) from node js. This is a server side access (like a cron activity) with no user interface.

From the documentation I understand that a code similar to this is to be used

```
...
const driveItemId = "<drive-item-id>";
const range = "Sheet1!A1:B2";

const response = await graphClient.api(`/drives/${driveItemId}/items/${driveItemId}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='${range}')?$select=values`).get();

const values = response.values;
console.log(values);

...
```

In one drive when I open a excel sheet, I notice the following is the URL

```
https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=<resid-value>&cid=<cid-value>&CT=<ct-value>&OR=ItemsView
```

Question is: **how do I use this to get the item id**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Graph API to search for the item

```
const graph = require('@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client');
const client = graph.Client.init({
  authProvider: (done) => {
    done(null, '<access-token>');
  }
});

const url = 'https://onedrive.live.com/edit.aspx?resid=<resid-value>&cid=<cid-value>&CT=<ct-value>&OR=ItemsView';

client.api('/me/drive/root/search(q=\'file:' + url + '\')').get((err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    const item = res.value[0];
    const itemId = item.id;
    console.log('Item ID:', itemId);
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh, okay. Let me give it a try. Thanks @Souvik

Comment: For some reason the above code (I converted it to an await since the above code just shows a blank with successful exit)  throws a fetch error. Just as an additional data point I forgot to mention: the file that is being accessed is an excel file of an individual user while the serverless function being tested is in the azure portal. The user is not part of the portal. Also, for purposes of testing, the file is shared with viewer access for all. Thanks for the help